# Abstract Algebra problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisﬁes the following conditions:

$f(x + t, y) = f(x, y) + ty$,

$f(x, t + y) = f(x, y) + tx$ and

$f(0, 0) = K$, a constant.

Then for all $x, y ∈ R , f(x, y)$ is equal to

(A) $K(x + y)$. (B) $K − xy$. (C) $K + xy$. (D) none of the above.

I just deduced $f(1,1)$ from $f(0,0)$. Is the answer (C) $K+xy$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, (C) is correct. Just check the properties:

1. $f(0,0) = K + 0 = K$
2. $f(x+t,y) = K + (x+t)y = K + xy + ty = f(x,y) + ty$
3. $f(x,t+y) = K + x(t+y) = K + xy + xt = f(x,y) + tx$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=f(x,y+0)=f(0+x,0)+yx=f(0,0)+x\cdot0+yx=K+xy$$